# Using datatables with Laravel Chunk/Cursor eloquent method to process larage data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, datatables, yajra-datatable

I am trying to read full table and put it into datatable, I used below code but it's not memory friendly:

```
$result = FullReport::all();
return DataTables::of($result)->make(true);
```

So I searched and found that there's `Chunk` and `Cursor` funtions that may help in memory limit error.

https://dudi.dev/optimize-laravel-database-queries/

Any suggestion how to use it with datatable, as I did below but didn't work:

```
$result = FullReport::all()->chunk(100);
return DataTables::of($result[0])->make(true);
```

As it retrieves only 100 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [yajra](https://yajrabox.com/) laravel data table, don't have to manage pagination manually.See [Eloquent via Factory](https://yajrabox.com/docs/laravel-datatables/10.0/engine-eloquent#factory).Just pass model query instance and make datatable server side processing.

```
$model = FullReport::query();
 
return DataTables::of($model)->toJson();
```

or

```
$model = FullReport::query();
 
return DataTables::of($model)->toJson();
```

Client Side add datatable configuration

```
processing: true,
serverSide: true,
```

Ref : [Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side) and [processing](https://datatables.net/reference/option/processing)